# DataSet Cascade Update

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dataset

I have ASP.NET application that uses DataSets.  All required relations are already set in the database and in the DataSet.

How can I update primary key in parent table and be sure that all fields in other tables related to that key are updated too?

If I perform `Adapter.Update(...)`, the related tables stay untouched.

Answer (score 1):

You should not ever need to update a primary key value.  It's a unique identifier for a row and should be reliable to be used as such.

What are you actually trying to accomplish and maybe we can suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: I have two options: changing whole model by adding new primary key column and converting old primary key field to new regular field; or change wrong values in primary keys. It is possible with database management software, but not from dataset...

Comment: How can your existing primary key values be "wrong"?  Are they supposed to match the values from some other database or table?  If so, they're not really primary keys, but foreign keys.  I'd suggest that you keep your existing primary keys and add another column that contains the foreign key values.